# SimpleModal does not work in iframe (IE only)

Tags: html, iframe, simplemodal

I have used SimpleModal to popup an information in a web page but when I embed that page with iframe in another page SimpleModal does not work properly in Internet E9. It only shows the black transparent layer (overlay?) only and stops when I click on the link.

Can anyone help me?

THanks...

Comment: Please post a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/ and provide the link when it's ready.

Comment: We really need more context, not just to help solve your problem but for future visitors to be able to find your problem and the solution. Can you add more information?

Answer (score 0):

I have achived this issue with adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` in `<head>` tag.

Thanks...